# How to use fb.data.query to get friends info

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api

I am using javascript sdk to use logged in user's info. It works fine. I want them to export their friend list. I have asked extended permissions on login. But I dont know how to build fb.data.query to get friend's name, profile url, education info and work history.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, hope it helps.

```
var query = FB.Data.query('select uid, first_name, last_name, work, from user where uid={0}', response.id);

query.wait(function(rows) {
var loginData = {fb_uid: rows[0].uid, 
                first_name: rows[0].first_name,
                last_name: rows[0].last_name,
                employer: rows[0].work[0].employer.name,
                position: rows[0].work[0].position.name
    };
}
```